# Why is it called 'Code First' from database in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've made an application in ASP.NET MVC. I first created an database in SQL Server and then installed the Entity Framework in Visual Studio and used the Entity Data Model Wizard, I selected the 'Code First from database', and it generated the derived DbContext Class and the models from the database.

My question is basically, why is it called 'Code First' when all the classes are generated based on the database - I've basically written no code, apart from the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Code first refers to generating the database from your POCO but typically when you are targeting an existing database you can have the VS tools create the classes for you to get up and running quickly.

That is the impression I go from typing [Code First from database](https://www.google.com/search?q=Code+First+from+database) into google.

[Code-First from an Existing Database:](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-from-existing-database.aspx)

> Entity Framework provides an easy way to use code-first approach for
>   an existing database. It will create entity classes for all the tables
>   & views in your existing database and configure it with
>   DataAnnotations attributes and Fluent API.

Additional source:

[ScottGu's Blog - Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database)

> EF “Code First” works great with existing databases, and enables a
>   very nice code-centric development approach with them. In particular,
>   it enables you to use clean “plain old classes” (aka POCO) for your
>   model objects, and cleanly map them to/from the database using either
>   the default mapping conventions or by overriding them with custom
>   schema mapping rules.